# Transform files from one S3 bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, orc

i am new to amazon aws. i have a use case to read ORC files from one s3 bucket, convert that to JSON files and write to another s3 bucket.
Volume is about 100G and roughly a thousand files everyday.
I should be able to run this on-demand or schedule to run daily. what are the options i should consider?

any ideas would be helpful

Comment: It all depends on the size of the files, how many of them you have. You simply haven't provided much info in your question to even begin thinking about this.

Comment: @Marcin  Volume is about 100G and roughly a thousand files everyday.

Comment: I mean how big is one file? If its tiny, a lambda could be used, if not other service must be considered.

Comment: @Marcin max size of a file would be around 100MB-200MB

Comment: So these files uploaded one-by-one, and you have to transform them after each upload?

Comment: @Marcin no, there will be a bulk upload nightly.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon Athena**

You can use Amazon Athena to convert file formats via the `CREATE TABLE AS` command. See: [Creating a Table from Query Results (CTAS) - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html)

The question then becomes how to send the commands to Athena. For this, you could schedule an AWS Lambda function to run, which starts an Amazon EC2 instance. Then, run a script on the instance to send all the commands to Amazon Athena. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

**AWS Glue ETL job**

Alternatively, you could create an AWS Glue ETL job that uses Spark to transform the data. See: [Built-In Transforms - AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/built-in-transforms.html)